# Failed to install on virtual device

Tags: android, eclipse

It's my first application 
The application was running twice on the virtual device actually
I just added an imageview but then ctrl+z 
it continues giving this error in the console
I tried many emulators but still having the error

[2015-02-27 18:39:05 - IdealBodyWeight] Failed to install IdealBodyWeight.apk on device 'emulator-5554!

[2015-02-27 18:39:05 - IdealBodyWeight] (null)

[2015-02-27 18:39:05 - IdealBodyWeight] Launch canceled!

Comment: try restarting your virtual device

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

- Uninstall the application inside the AVD
- Reset the AVD
- Remove the AVD and recrete it